# How To Persist and Fetch a List in Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to Umbraco and want to perform the following tasks in it.

1. Store a list of movies in the database using an entry form.
2. Fetch the records of the movies and display them in a page for which I have a template.

I don't want to use JQuery, AngularJS etc., but rather to do it on the server side.

Any guidance will be appreciated greatly.

*P.S. I have some knowledge about Umbraco fundamentals and its Partial View Macros.*

Comment: Do you want to store in a database of as umbraco documents in the tree?  Do you already have a database and tables filled with data?  Are you asking about integration or rather about how to start with umbraco?

Comment: @dampee I am asking about how to start with Umbraco.
I want to store the list in the Umbraco's database using a form and don't already have a database. Then -the main part of the problem- load some records and show them in a list (just like GridView) in a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, I am assuming that you wish to create movie nodes in Umbraco's content tree, e.g. under a page called "All Movies".

Firstly, it is *very* bad practice to allow a form in your website to write directly to your content tree. This opens up to a whole world of issues like users spamming your db and filling it up with rubbish.

However, in order to create content from a form in Umbraco using the MVC approach, you need to review the documentation here http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/. To summarise though, you need:

- An action on a SurfaceController for handling your form post requests

  ```
  public class MovieSurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
  {
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult SaveMovie(SaveMovieViewModel model)
      {    
          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
              return CurrentUmbracoPage();

          return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
      }
  }
  ```
- Your form needs to post to your SurfaceController action, e.g.

  ```
  @using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm("SaveMovie", "MovieSurface")) { ... }
  ```
- Then within your action you need to access the `ContentService` to create and save your Movie content, targeting the "All Movies" page as being the parent page.

  ```
  Services.ContentService.CreateContent(
      "Harold and Maude", allMoviesContent, "Movie", 0
  );
  ```

However, like I say this is bad practice and I show you just as an illustration. A much *better* approach would be to:

- Store the submitted values in a separate database table, i.e. separate from the core Umbraco database tables.
- Retrieve the movie values from this database table directly bypassing Umbraco completely.

You can do this by utilising the Petapoco `Database` instance that Umbraco is built upon:

```
ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database.Save(new Movie());
```

Or

```
var item = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database.Single<Movie>(movieId);
```

Even better would be to create a backoffce custom section where you could moderate the submitted Movie data (stored in your independent table) and save the Movie content from here into the content tree.

Comment: thank you so much but I was hopeful to get a guidance for the second part of the problem too. Anyway thank you; your answer is really educating and useful.

Comment: Well that's the easy bit! If you store the movies as content, the you just access them via the standard `RenderModel` object in your view. If you're storing them in a database as Movie records, then just query the database and pass them down in your model.

Comment: What if I do not want to work with (add) nodes in the document tree but rather to insert records to the database. Can you please help?

Comment: Not really because that is far too vague and you haven't shown any signs of trying anything first. However, the process is no different from what I have described but substitute where I am writing to Umbraco's API for writing to a database. You have to choose a data layer/orm (e.g. EF, NHibernate, Petapoco, LinqToSQL, Ado.Net etc) and then just use that to write to the db.

Comment: I have added some code to show how you can use Umbraco's internal implementation of Petapoco to save and retrieve strongly typed data from the database. This can be done in the controller and then passed down as part of the view model.

Comment: That's so kind of you. It is exactly what I was looking for. I asked this because I have always coded against conventional business or data layer to do the CRUD and working with content nodes is totally new to me. I just wasn't able to figure out how to translate CRUD operations to Umbraco nodes language. Additionally I have used EF from its early versions and used it in almost every data access scenario since, and I couldn't even think that such a robust solution like Umbraco could be built with a minimal ORM like Petapoco. Really amazing!